# MySQL select N latest rows for each product from 3 relational tables

Tags: mysql

Now i have this code which return latest record for each product. But i don't know how to modify this to get for example 3 latest rows for each product.
I want to compare latest product prices and i need few latest rows of each.

### shops

```
id | shopId
-----------
1  | 2345
2  | 6573
```

### products

```
id | shopId | title    | active | pDateAdded          | pDateUpdate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18 |   1    | Honda    | 1      | 2021-03-07 01:56:34 | 2021-03-07 04:36:34
19 |   2    | Subaru   | 1      | 2021-03-07 03:43:34 | 2021-03-08 04:36:34
20 |   1    | VW       | 1      | 2021-03-07 07:21:34 | 2021-03-09 04:36:34
21 |   2    | Ford     | 0      | 2021-03-07 11:37:34 | 2021-03-10 04:36:34
```

### prices

```
id  | shopId | productId | price | dDateAdded
-----------------------------------------------------
224 | 1      | 18       | 2385  | 2021-03-09 12:39:57
225 | 2      | 19       | 1523  | 2021-03-09 13:14:44
226 | 1      | 20       | 5489  | 2021-03-09 17:32:18
227 | 1      | 18       | 2256  | 2021-03-10 18:22:13
228 | 2      | 19       | 1600  | 2021-03-10 21:33:21
229 | 1      | 20       | 5321  | 2021-03-10 14:15:56
230 | 1      | 18       | 2137  | 2021-03-11 05:55:25
231 | 2      | 19       | 1666  | 2021-03-11 17:31:49
232 | 1      | 20       | 5001  | 2021-03-11 20:18:01
```

This command return only 1 latest record from `prices` table for every product from `products` table for specific `shopId`

```
SELECT s.*, c.*, d.*
FROM shops AS s
LEFT JOIN products AS c ON c.shopId = s.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT productId, MAX(dDateAdded) MaxDate
FROM prices
GROUP BY productId
) MaxDates
ON MaxDates.productId = c.id
LEFT JOIN prices AS d ON d.productId = c.id AND d.shopId = s.id AND MaxDates.MaxDate = d.dDateAdded
WHERE s.id = ".$shopId."
```

For example if `shopId=1` this command get only that records (I omitted here the data from the other tables that are retrieved):

```
230 | 1      | 18       | 2137  | 2021-03-11 05:55:25
232 | 1      | 20       | 5001  | 2021-03-11 20:18:01
```

But i want to get for example 2 latest records for every product where `shopId=1`, so the records which i want to get:

```
(shops)id | (shops)shopId | title | active | price | dDateAdded
 1        | 2345          | Honda | 1      | 2256  | 2021-03-10 18:22:13
 1        | 2345          | Honda | 1      | 2137  | 2021-03-10 14:15:56
 1        | 2345          | VW    | 1      | 5321  | 2021-03-11 05:55:25
 1        | 2345          | VW    | 1      | 5001  | 2021-03-11 20:18:01
```

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: mysql ver. 5.7.33

Comment: In addition, show db schema, sample data, current and expected output, column corresponding to `product`, and column to order.

Comment: I added the table structure and the example I want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select N latest rows needs to allocate row number and to filter by N rows. However, the ROW_NUMBER function is not supported in MySQL 5.7.
So that you need to simulate the ROW_NUMBER function like the follwing:

You can get the desired result by adding subquery with row number to your query like the below:

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUpzAXAy7YqVNobQqSn9nD/2)

```sql
SELECT
  s.id,
  s.shopId,
  c.title,
  c.active,
  d.price,
  d.dDateAdded
FROM shops AS s
LEFT JOIN products AS c ON c.shopId = s.id
LEFT JOIN prices AS d ON d.productId = c.id AND d.shopId = s.id
--
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    p1.id,
    COUNT(p2.dDateAdded) + 1 row_num
  FROM prices p1 LEFT JOIN prices p2
  ON p1.shopId = p2.shopId AND
     p1.productId = p2.productId AND
     p1.dDateAdded < p2.dDateAdded
  GROUP BY p1.id, p1.shopId, p1.productId, p1.dDateAdded
) AS w
ON d.id=w.id
--
WHERE
  s.id = 1 AND
  w.row_num <= 2
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUpzAXAy7YqVNobQqSn9nD/1)

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  shopId,
  productId,
  price,
  dDateAdded
FROM (
  SELECT p1.*,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM prices p2
      WHERE
        p1.shopId = p2.shopId AND
        p1.productId = p2.productId AND
        p1.dDateAdded < p2.dDateAdded
    ) row_num
  FROM prices p1
) p
WHERE
  shopId = 1 AND
  row_num <= 2
ORDER BY id
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUpzAXAy7YqVNobQqSn9nD/0)

```sql
SELECT p.* FROM prices p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    p1.id,
    COUNT(p2.dDateAdded) + 1 row_num
  FROM prices p1 LEFT JOIN prices p2
  ON p1.shopId = p2.shopId AND
     p1.productId = p2.productId AND
     p1.dDateAdded < p2.dDateAdded
  GROUP BY
    p1.id,
    p1.shopId,
    p1.productId,
    p1.dDateAdded
) w
ON p.id=w.id
WHERE
  p.shopId = 1 AND
  w.row_num <= 2
ORDER BY p.id
```

[Other way using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239851/mysql-5-7-getting-the-row-number)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but i'm afraid that isn't what i want. Maybe i write one more time what i want to have on output. I edited main post.

Comment: Added a query to get your desired result.

Comment: i was using this, but when i have many rows it's very slow query. is there any way to do this faster on mysql 8? maybe with ROW_NUMBER function which you was writing?